# Glassfish 4.1 jar locking in windows

Tags: windows, glassfish, locking, glassfish-4.1, glassfish-4.1.1

I recently upgraded Glassfish from 4.0 to 4.1 and i'm on Windows 8.1.

Now when i try to undeploy/redeploy my application (WAR), asadmin hangs indefinitely.

The problem is that all JARs inside `domain1\applications\myapp\WEB-INF\lib` are locked and cannot be deleted until Glassfish is stopped or killed.

Workaround needed!

---

**update**

The issue is filed [GLASSFISH-21283](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21283). As you can see there's no interest in solving it...

Glassfish-4.1.1 still doesn't allow undeploy/redeploy...
Tested Payara too, same problem... I give up.

But a question remains: how many people use glassfish for development/production on windows? A dozen worldwide?
Cause this is a critical issue, unresolved in more than one year.

Comment: Nope. I'm using GF 4.0 for development and 4.1 for production. Waiting for 4.1.1 :(

Comment: Another approach I did was use docker to create a glassfish installation for me to develop on.

Comment: Now I use JRebel, so no more redeploys.

Comment: tried glassfish 4.1.1, still locking :(

Comment: I know... Maybe in 2024 with glassfish-8.5 we'll be able to undeploy... However I switched to Wildfly 9 and Hibernate, and now I sleep much better ;)